Lookup Search Result New Button Override
I am currently trying to override the New button for an object (User Group in this case) when it's on a lookup in the declarative view. The optimal way to solve this would be to remove it, but after looking it up, it seems that this is not an option.
I thought that in if I overwrite the new button for the 'New' action, and redirect it to another page (whether it's a VF page, or a seperate Lightning page), it would redirect me if I click on this button. However, it still opens the declarative view.
Is this not possible? I thought this was updated in 2020 - Winter 20 - change in behaviour - "New" button on Lookup search results

